# Adding XML file to the last element of existing XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a XML file like this, let's name is XML_old:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
// Description : ahbbus12alda.xml
// modifications; this notice must be included on any copy.
-->
<ipxact:component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"             
xmlns:ipxact="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014 
http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014/index.xsd">
   <ipxact:vendor>spiritconsortium.org</ipxact:vendor>
   <ipxact:library>Leon2RTL</ipxact:library>
   <ipxact:name>ahbbus12</ipxact:name>
   <ipxact:version>1.3</ipxact:version>
   <ipxact:busInterfaces>
      <ipxact:busInterface>
         <ipxact:name>AHBClk</ipxact:name>
      </ipxact:busInterface>
    </ipxact:busInterfaces>  
</ipxact:component>
```

Also, I have another XML file, XML_1, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ipxact:component1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:ipxact="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014 
 http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014/index.xsd">
    <ipxact:vendor1>spiritconsortium.org</ipxact:vendor1>
    <ipxact:library1>Leon2RTL</ipxact:library1>
    <ipxact:name1>ahbbus34</ipxact:name1>
    <ipxact:version1>1.3</ipxact:version1>
    <ipxact:busInterfaces1>
        <ipxact:busInterface1>
            <ipxact:name1>AHBClk</ipxact:name1>
        <ipxact:busInterface1>
    <ipxact:busInterfaces1>
</ipxact:component1>
```

I want to add XML_1 to the XML_old as a last child of component element in XML_old file and create a new XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
// Description : ahbbus12alda.xml
// modifications; this notice must be included on any copy.
-->
<ipxact:component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          
xmlns:ipxact="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014"         
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014 
http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014/index.xsd">
   <ipxact:vendor>spiritconsortium.org</ipxact:vendor>
   <ipxact:library>Leon2RTL</ipxact:library>
   <ipxact:name>ahbbus12</ipxact:name>
   <ipxact:version>1.3</ipxact:version>
   <ipxact:busInterfaces>
      <ipxact:busInterface>
         <ipxact:name>AHBClk</ipxact:name>
      </ipxact:busInterface>
    </ipxact:busInterfaces> 
    <ipxact:component1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ipxact="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014 
     http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014/index.xsd">
        <ipxact:vendor1>spiritconsortium.org</ipxact:vendor1>
        <ipxact:library1>Leon2RTL</ipxact:library1>
        <ipxact:name1>ahbbus34</ipxact:name1>
        <ipxact:version1>1.3</ipxact:version1>
        <ipxact:busInterfaces1>
            <ipxact:busInterface1>
                <ipxact:name1>AHBClk</ipxact:name1>
            <ipxact:busInterface1>
        <ipxact:busInterfaces1>
    </ipxact:component1>
</ipxact:component>
```

I wonder how can I do this? I appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Your other XML files is not a well-formed XML as the colon namespaces are not declared and numbers may not be used for local names.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks. I edited it. So, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Still not well-formed. Where is `IDEA` defined with `xmlns`? You should definitely post actual XML as any solution posed may not work with your actual data, leading to more frustration. If XML arrived like that, check how it is generated upstream as it is not using a proper DOM library.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks again for your notice. Does it work now?